# Speed up hashmap writes

Tags: java, performance, hashmap

I have a Hashmap composed of a fixed number of keys which is preventively populated. Now, in a loop I have to check each key to replace the value in case it must be changed.

Sadly, it is pretty slow due to the number of iterations required. I really would like to maintain a key-value structure because it is used on the top and at the end of my module but I would like to improve the performance at least.

I also thought to an arrayList in order to improve insertion time, but in that case the search would be slower and I'd lose the key-value feature.
What if I sort the arraylist on the key at the beginning and then look for values with a binary search?

Is there a better solution to search and write on a map?

Thanks,

EDIT: Code

```
  for (Entry<String, VariableInfo> entry : VariablesMap.entrySet()){

  String varName = entry.getKey();
  VariableInfo info = entry.getValue();

  Object value = info.convertToValue();

        DialogWait dialogWindow = new DialogWait();                     
        SwingWorker<Void, Void> swingWorker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {

                while(newTimeSet != _record.getCurrentTimeMs()) {

                    _record.stepForward();

                    if(valuesMap.get(varName)!=value)
                        valuesMap.put(varName, value);
                }
                dialogWindow.close();
                return null;
            }
        };

        swingWorker.execute();          
        dialogWindow.makeWait("Loading");                   
}
```

Comment: How large is your `HashMap`? And what is the type of the key?

Comment: Can you quantify "pretty slow"? How big is that map? What is the logic to decide if a key needs to be replaced? Can you show some code?

Comment: Why do you have to check each key to replace the values?

Comment: very likely you checked your keys by a loop of keySet(),  thus, you turned `O(1)` -> `O(n)` hashtable.get(key) is O(1). So show some codes of checking key and updating value.

Comment: If you *have to* iterate the structure because you need to check all the values, there's not much you can do on this end. Of course it would be faster if you were able to just access the entries you want to modify by key. If you want to speed up insertion time, an `ArrayList` is not helpful, because every time the internal array runs out of space, it's content has to be copied to a new, larger array (as an array cannot be resized: It's a linear data structure and gets a continuous block of memory).

Comment: I'll add some code editing the question. The keys are String (less than 15 literals), the values are Objects (a mix of chars, array of chars of few elements).
The Map contains around 2000 keys. I have to perform up to 1 million iterations. Depending on the user choice, this loop can be executed 1-3 times.
Basically the keys are parameters and the values are the values of the parameter in a particular time. The input is a list of values associated to the parameters in different times. When a button is pressed, each time is scanned and the values of the parameters in the map are updated.

Comment: 100.000 iterations* (count mistake). It takes around 3 minutes.

Comment: `if(valuesMap.get(varName)!=value)` looks risky. You probably want `! a.equals(b)` instead of ` a != b`

Comment: @Thilo you're right!

Answer (score 1):

> Now, in a loop I have to check each key to replace the value in case it must be changed.

Is there maybe a way to update the list, if the condition that the value must change becomes true? So basically, can you rewrite code outside the map, to react to the change, rather than the map changing periodically, depending on the state? This is usually a pretty strong improvement on performance, and will make your map way more useful, as it is much more up to date.

If you truly must check every entry in the Map periodically, then you have a runtime of `O(n)` by using `map.entrySet()` and iterating over it. It cannot be optimized, assuming that you cannot predict information about the mappings entered.

If you have certain entries, that change with a higher frequency or probability, you could optimize by applying a higher check-frequency there, than for the rest. For that, you could use a `LinkedHashMap`. With it, you can insert elements, and the list keeps track of the order of insertion. With it, you could easiely remember the last `n` changed elements, and prioritize them, over others.